# Set textView in Android Studio to display WiFi Strength

Tags: android, variables, text, wifi

**My WiFi Signal Strength Tester is Having Serious Issues**

***Errors I am getting:***

Got it working! Thanks All

```html
package com.example.wifilocator;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.wifi.WifiInfo;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.wifilocator.R;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}

class wifi {
    int signalStrength = 0;
    int loopToggle = 0;

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
    public void loop() throws InterruptedException {
        while (loopToggle == 0) {
            WifiManager signalStrength = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
            String wifiInfo = WifiManager.EXTRA_WIFI_INFO;
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

I am very new to Android Studio and developing. Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: You're missing a `}` at the end.

Comment: Always pay attention to the stack trace line number, in your case `last line/line 34`

Comment: I just added that last '}' and still having Gradle project sync failures. Thanks though!

Comment: Look for the logs. Search that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    class wifi {
    int signalStrength = 0;
    int loopToggle = 0;
    Context context = MainActivity.this ;


    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
    public void loop() throws InterruptedException {
        while (loopToggle == 0) {
            WifiManager signalStrength = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
            String wifiInfo = WifiManager.EXTRA_WIFI_INFO;
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }
```

You need To declare the Context of your class  , try this see if helps

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I tried this and got an error saying that it was not an "enclosing class". Any ideas?

Comment: I got it to run Gradle after adding the package name to the AndroidManifest file. Thanks for your time and help!

Comment: got the "not an enclosing class" error again. Any ideas?